# Hello Shue! (Cops)

Tags: cops-and-robbers, code-generation, hello-world

<sup>[Robbers thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243504/hello-shue-robbers)</sup>

In this [cops-and-robbers](/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers) challenge, your task is to write a program `h` that outputs "Hello Shue!". Next, you have to choose a string `i` and also write a [Shue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242897/golf-the-prime-numbers-in-shue) program `p`, so that `p(i)=h`. Your score is `len(p)+len(i)`. Your answer will contain the language of `h`, `i` and your score (please write the score as `len(p)+len(i)=score`). Robbers will try to find `p`. Note that any working `p`, that is as long as your `p` or shorter means that your answer is defeated, even if it wasn't the solution you intended. The undefeated cop answer with the smallest score wins (per language).

To understand this challenge let's look at an example submission in Python:

> Python 3, score 47+22=69
>
> `(rint?KH++lloooShu++K'`

Not included in the post is the following Shue program (`p`):

```
print("Hello Shue")
(=p
?=(
K="
++=e
ooo=o 
'=)
```

<sup>Note that there is a trailing space after the `o`</sup>

The first line is the program `h`. Next are a series of replacement rules. Let's see how they work.

With the input `(rint?KH++lloooShu++K'` (`i`) we can get to `h` like so

```
(rint?KH++lloooShu++K'
(rint(KH++lloooShu++K' - ?=(
print(KH++lloooShu++K' - (=p
print("H++lloooShu++K' - K="
print("H++lloooShu++K) - '=)
print("H++lloooShu++") - K="
print("H++llo Shu++")  - ooo=o 
print("Hello Shu++")   - ++=e
print("Hello Shue")    - ++=e
```

If your code `h` contains equals signs, backslashes or newlines, escape them with `\=`,`\\` and `\n` respectively in the Shue program `p` (but not in the input `i`).   If your code contains nulls or non-unicode bytes, don't worry, Shue is byte-oriented.

Comment: I think this challenge could really do by starting with a sentence or two explaining what this cops and robbers is about before introducing variable names. In particular, what is the idea of Shue and why should we bother learning this language you made up and what makes it interesting for this challenge?

Comment: Do we need a trailing newline in the output of "Hello, Shue"?

Comment: @l4m2 no, you must use the exact same `i` as the cop

Comment: @l4m2 I mean, if a shorter `i` was allowed, you could just say that i="" and p="print('Hello Shue!')\n=print('Hello Shue!')" and win every time.

Comment: OK there's no length limit of `h` and whatever

Comment: @l4m2 No, but of course the longer `h` is the worse your score is.

Comment: Is waiting time one week like other [tag:cops-and-robbers]?

Comment: May want to correct the examples to include the exclamation mark...

Comment: Also, the interpreter in the linked challenge seems not to handle escaped `=` correctly?

Answer (score 2):

## Python 3, score 163+563=726, Safe

> In this cops-and-robbers challenge, your task is to write a program h that outputs "Hello Shue!". Next, you have to choose a string i and also write a Shue program p, so that p(i)=h. Your score is len(p)+len(i). Your answer will contain the language of h, i and your score (please write the score as len(p)+len(i)=score). Robbers will try to find p. Note that any working p, that is as long as your p or shorter means that your answer is defeated, even if it wasn't the solution you intended. The undefeated cop answer with the smallest score wins (per language).

Not that fun though

```
print("Hello Shue")
I=
n=
 =
t=
h=
i=
s=
c=
o=
-=
a=
d=
b=
e=
r=
l=
g=
,=
y=
u=
k=
w=
p=
m=
.=
N=
x=
v=
S=
(=
)=
\==
Y=
+=
f=
R=
'=
T=
=nt(
```

actually 140 bytes

Answer (score 2):

## Vyxal, score 28+19=47

```
\a:ȯ≤∨I:C‹C\Hp5‛ SṀṅ
```

[Try input online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJcXGE6yK/iiaTiiKhJOkPigLlDXFxIcDXigJsgU+G5gOG5hSIsIiIsIiJd)
I don't know if it'll be an easy crack, or if I forgot something.

Comment: I think 28 plus 19 is 47...

Comment: @ophact this is embarrassing... I changed 20 to 19 and forgot to update