# Hello Shue! (Robbers)

Tags: cops-and-robbers, code-generation, hello-world

<sup>[Cops thread (read first)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/243503/hello-shue-cops)</sup>

Robbers, your task is to find a [Shue](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/242897/golf-the-prime-numbers-in-shue) program `p` that when given the cops input `i`, outputs a program `h`, which outputs "Hello Shue!". The length of your `p` has to be less than or equal to the length of the cop's `p`. The robber with the most cracks wins.